# In a multi-user app, checking if the current blog post belongs to the logged in user and url suggestion needed

Tags: django, url, authentication, autosuggest

Newbie alert: I have the following code. My blog app is a multi-user app. Once any user creates a post and visits his/her profile, they should see only the post they own, which is simple.

`post_id` is the primary key of the Post model which increments on its own. The problem with multi-user app is that users may try to put `/<post_id>/` of something that does not belong to them. I am trying to catch that problem here. It will be obvious to them after a while that their `post_id`'s are not incrementing and some are 'missing' because them belong to someone else.

- Is it a good idea to show the pk of the post in url to grab it and check in the `edit_post` view whether it belongs to the user?
- Is there a better suggestion than to show the primary key in the url?
- How else can I get the current `post_id` if it is not in the url and I believe I need `post_id` to grab the current post the user wants to edit.

#### urls.py

```
(r'^create/$', create_post),
(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/edit/$', edit_post),
```

#### models.py:

```
class Post (models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, help_text="required, name of the post") 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, help_text="user this post belongs to") 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name 

class PostForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
            model = Post
```

#### views.py

```
#----------------------------View-------------------------------------- 
@login_required 
def create_post (request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST) 
        if post_form.is_valid(): 
            post.save() 
            return render_to_response('home.html') 
        else: 
            return HttpResponse('not working') 
    else: 
        post_form = PostForm() 
        return render_to_response('create.html', {'post_form':post_form })

@login_required 
def edit_post (request, post_id): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST) 
        """
        Stuff to check whether the 
        current logged in user owns 
        this post.
        like 
        if post_user = Post(pk=post_id).user:
            show the post here.
        """
       else: 
            return HttpResponse('not working') 
    else: 
        post_form = PostForm() 
        return render_to_response('create.html', {'post_form':post_form })\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to show the pk of the post in url to grab it and check in the edit_post view whether it belongs to the user?

You absolutely should check the ownership of the post in your edit view.

> Is there a better suggestion than to show the primary key in the url?

There are other options: for example the id's don't actually need to be unique- just unique for each user.  You could have an id that increments for each user, rather than globally.  Personally I don't know if it's worth the hassle.  I think using the primary key is fine, provided you make it secure, and you don't care if people can deduce your volume by looking at it.

> How else can I get the current post_id if it is not in the url and I believe I need post_id to grab the current post the user wants to edit.

Like I said, you could do a lookup of another column along with the user, or you could even create random ids (for example a truncated UUID) for each post.

For your edit view, you could secure it simply by doing something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required 
def edit_post (request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id, user=request.user)
...
```

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield you can see an example here http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/defining-your-models.html

Answer (score 1):

in your views.py you can use something like:

```
@login_required 
def edit_post (request, post_id):
    post = None
    if post_id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        if post.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponse("You can only edit your own posts")

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post) 
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Sucess")
    else: 
        post_form = PostForm(instance=post) 

    return render_to_response('edit.html', {'post_form':post_form })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is just perfect for [django-guardian](http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/). This package already implements per object permissions and there is a function named get_objects_for_user that works as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from projects.models import Project
from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user

def user_dashboard(request, template_name='projects/dashboard.html'):
 projects = get_objects_for_user(request.user, 'projects.view_project')
 return render_to_response(template_name, {'projects': projects},
    RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see, the example is almost what you need, but for posts.